# Reversing Of A Linked List

Tags: pointers, data-structures, linked-list, reverse, singly-linked-list

I am not able to understand why we are using next node in this function, if we look at it practically it is not required but when I attempt to remove the next node pointer, the program is giving me output as only one node. It would be great if someone could explain to me what I Am interpreting wrong in this program and would help me out in understanding this concept.

```
//node is a datatype of struct *node and I have used typedef to make it simpler.    

node Reverse(node head)
{
node temp,prevnode=NULL;
node nextnode;
temp=head;
while(temp!=NULL)
{   
    nextnode=temp->next;
    temp->next=prevnode;
    prevnode=temp;
    temp=nextnode;
}
head=prevnode;
return(head);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**So basically what you're doing is traversing a linkedlist, and making all of the links point <- instead of ->.**

### So the loop is

Starting with the temp node, which is at the head

- nextnode = Exactly that, you're grabbing the next node in the list from current(temp)
- Then you set the current node's next to the previous node
- Then you set the previous node to the current node, so you can move on
- Then you change your pointer to the nextnode

If you don't start out by setting nextnode, you'll overwrite it in the step of setting the current node's next (to the previous node)

Also, the reason why you're only getting an output of 1 node when you remove the nextnode variable, is that you're overwriting the next node to previous node at the beginning, which is nothing. After that, you move onto that nothing node, which ends the loop. Then your head is the previous node, which is just the first node you started with.